# Triple boot Windows 10 Ubuntu 16 and Kali

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, kali-linux, grub2, ubuntu-16.04

I have been running Win and Ubuntu just fine, and then I have installed Kali and now I am facing the following issue. Just after installation of Kali I have rebooted and were able to access Kali boot loader, but then I have shut down the pc and used windows, and now when i try to access the kali boot loader it only offers me the Ubuntu while Kali is not listed, however when I enter the Ubuntu I can clearly see that Kali is still installed on its partition. It is just that I can't access it through the grub loader. I do not know what the issue could be. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Windows 8.1, Ubuntu 17.10, and Kali on my pc. Kali ran well after my first installation but I installed it again. Then I have faced a issue on grub rescue . Then I tried following commands on ubuntu and now it is working.

```
sudo update-grub
```

After this enter your password. Then try,

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Now those three os are working correctly.